# Peanut butter logs

Tags: candy

I have a candy recipe for peanut butter logs which calls for 3 cups of powdered sugar.  This is TOO SWEET.  Is there any way to cut the sweetness?

Comment: Please provide the full recipe.

Comment: Related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10257/peanut-butter-treat-using-less-sugar-and-less-butter

Answer (score 1):

I have used 1 cup of soft fine brown sugar and 1/2 cup of powdered sugar, as a substitute for 3 cups of powdered sugar. It changed the consistency and it worked out fine.